# Writing to Excel with a changing hashmap and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, hashmap

I am using nodeJS to collect data from a page with a log in, everytime a button is pressed, I get the time, who pressed the button, and which button they pressed.

I want to put it into excel, or somewhere else (if anyone has a recommendation), where this is the output:

```
    |john|joe|amanda
```

1:00    | 2 |  b   |  c |

1:01   | 4   |  a |     3 |

etc. etc.

This would be where each name has the values it pressed below it.

Putting it into excel is not the problem. The problem is making sure that each users data goes in their column.
How can I iterate through excel, quickly to make sure each value is put into the correct key? There will be 50 users, so speed and efficiency will be important.

I will elaborate more if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So for each click, you have to read the excel file, loop through it and find the cells to put the data in. Or you can store the last cell for each user, next time user clicks you can put exactly in the next cell.

Comment: I am worried about the memory and time it would take for each click to reread the excel file.